# Match a java main class with regexp

Tags: java, regex, emacs, elisp

I'm writing a plugin for emacs to compile and run a java source file with one keystroke.
Now I would like to find out the name of the main class or if there is none.
Anyone knows how to match a java main class name with regexp?

My first thought, in pseudo code regex is

- find the first word preceded by "class " and succeeded by "{"..."public static void main(String[]"

edit-
this is how far I've come. Not fully functionally yet but almost...

```
(?<=class ).*[^ ](?= *{.*public static void main)
```

I hate regex but still i like it. It's just that it's so hard to master.

Comment: Does JDE not already do this, maybe can you bolt your plugin onto that save you reinventing the wheel for the common stuff, you'd have an instant audience for your mode/commands then too.

Comment: If you want to get really technical, you would need to look for "static public" as well as the modifiers may occur in either order. And it can be declared final too, even if that's superfluous. You'd also need to see that there is one argument of type "String[]". And it'd work to declare it as "String[] args" or "String args[]" or "String... args". Not sure how robust this has to be.

Comment: true, it doesn't have to be waterproof. I solved it partially for now by simply using the file name i.e the public class name which I most often put my main class in. Probably don't need regex. really should go to sleep now too... but thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

The main class in Java does not have to have any particular name. In fact, a Java project can have several main classes, all with different names.

Comment: What i really mean is how do I match any class name in my file that contains a main function. Probably should have mad myself clearer.

Comment: Regular expressions won't do this.